# operator overloading - overloading *

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the * operator to do multiplications between my object and double types / the same object type.
I've overloaded the operator twice

```
Rational operator*(const Rational&) const;
Rational operator*(double) const;
```

The first one covers a case of t1 * t2;

The second covers a case of t1 * 3.8474;

But I want to cover the third case as-well of 3.8474 * t1;

How do I do it ? My mind is telling me that in-order to do it I need to overload the double type * operator but I don't know if it's possible ?

Comment: You'd overload the non-member version of the operator. I'd do that in all cases anyway.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Mind showing what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `3.8474 * t1` by overloading a global `operator*()`:

```
Rational operator*(double, const Rational&);
```

In general, I usually overload operators with global functions rather than with member functions. For example, the member functions that you have can be equivalently implemented with the following global functions:

```
Rational operator*(const Rational&, const Rational&);
Rational operator*(const Rational&, double);
```

Comment: oh so it's like defining both right and left side of the * operator ? so it's like 'global' * operator for all types ?

Comment: @Tugal.44 "global" means that the function is not inside a class or namespace. This allows you more control over both the left and right side of the operator, yes.